# vscode extension. How can I get a file body by filename

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I write my own extension for proprietary language (Using *LSP* - *language server protocol*) and this extension parsing a source code. When parser takes a string like `import "Filename.ext"` (in c++ is `#include "fileName.h"`), i must find this file "Filename.ext" and take body of this file for parsing. Client side have  "workspace.findFiles(name);" but it don't work in server side. Pls tell me how can i get a file by file name in server side. Create a function on client side and **import** to server side **don't work**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On server side:

```
export function GetFileRequest(nameInter:string) {
    connection.sendRequest("getFile", nameInter).then( (body : string) => {
        if (body != undefined && body.length) pushImports(body);
    });
}
```

on client side:
in *function activate(context: ExtensionContext)* after client.start();

```
    client.onReady().then(() => {
        client.onRequest("getFile", (nameInter : string) : Promise<string> => { return getFile(nameInter); } );
    });
```

and async function on client side:

```
async function getFile(name):Promise<string>{
    let uri:Uri = undefined;
    let text:string = undefined;
    await workspace.findFiles(name, null, 1).then((value)=> {
        if (value.length) {
            uri=value[0];
        }
    });
    if (uri!=undefined) {
        let textDocument;
        await workspace.openTextDocument(uri).then((value)=>textDocument = value);
        text = textDocument.getText();
    }
    return text;
}
```

This code will return a text from file to server side.